# histogram matching in Python

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, cdf

I am trying to do histogram matching of simulated data to observed precipitation data. The below shows a simple simulated case. I got the CDF of both the simulated and observed data and got stuck theree. I hope a clue would help me to get across..Thanks you in advance

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import scipy.stats as st


sim = st.gamma(1,loc=0,scale=0.8) # Simulated
obs = st.gamma(2,loc=0,scale=0.7) # Observed
x = np.linspace(0,4,1000)
simpdf = sim.pdf(x)
obspdf = obs.pdf(x)
plt.plot(x,simpdf,label='Simulated')
plt.plot(x,obspdf,'r--',label='Observed')
plt.title('PDF of Observed and Simulated Precipitation')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()

plt.figure(1)
simcdf = sim.cdf(x)
obscdf = obs.cdf(x)
plt.plot(x,simcdf,label='Simulated')
plt.plot(x,obscdf,'r--',label='Observed')
plt.title('CDF of Observed and Simulated Precipitation')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()

# Inverse CDF
invcdf = interp1d(obscdf,x)
transfer_func = invcdf(simcdf)

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(transfer_func,x,'g-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do that you can't?

Comment: @Ben, I am trying to the CDF matching/ histogram matching as shown in the image here.. http://s8.postimage.org/4txybzz8l/test.jpg. I am not able to inverse the CDF of the observed data which is next step.

Comment: Looks like you need to interpolate the CDF for your required values of y, then plot it with the old values of x.

Comment: @tiago,  I would really appreciate if you could put the solution.

Comment: @subash, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) I'm not going to write code for you. Your example code is mostly plots, and you don't seem to have tried anything to solve this problem. Asking for the code is just not what SO is about.

Comment: @tiago, My bad I did'nt put what i had tried.added to the code nw.. It could'nt generate the same transfer function as shown in plot (c) of http://s8.postimage.org/4txybzz8l/test.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your code, and got the following error:

```
ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.
```

If you look at the plot of your two CDFs it is pretty straight forward to figure out what is going on:

[image]

When you now define `invcdf = interp1d(obscdf, x)`, notice that `obscdf` ranges from

```
>>> obscdf[0]
0.0
>>> obscdf[-1]
0.977852889924409
```

and so `invcdf` can only interpolate values between those limits: beyond them we would have to do extrapolation, which is not all that well defined. SciPy's default behavior is to raise an error when asked to extrapolate. Which is exactly what happens when you ask for `invcdf(simcdf)`, because

```
>>> simcdf[-1]
0.99326205300091452
```

is beyond the interpolation range.

If you read [the `interp1d` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) you will see that this behavior can be modified doing

```
invcdf = interp1d(obscdf, x, bounds_error=False)
```

and now everything works out fine, although you need to reverse the order of your plotting arguments to `plt.plot(x, transfer_func,'g-')` to get the same as in the figure you posted:

[image]

Comment: @Jaime.. Thank you.. I made the changes as suggested and could generate all the 4 plots as shown in the link i posted. I accepted your answer.